# how to do a vlookup in pandas with counts

Tags: pandas, merge, count, pivot, vlookup

I have the two following input dataframes :

```
df_item_in_cat
      a     b     c     d
0     A     A     B     A
1     B     B     E     B
2     C     E     F     E
3     D     F     G     G

df_charac_by_cat
    cat      charac
0     a          10
1     b          20
2     c          25
3     d          15
```

And I would like to produce the below dataframe :

```
df
   item   cat_nb   sum_charac
0     A        3           45
1     B        4           70
2     C        1           10
3     D        1           10
4     E        2           45
5     F        2           45
6     G        2           40
```

where :

- cat_nb is the nb of columns where each item appear on df_item_in_cat
- sum_charac is the sum of charac from df_charac_by_cat of the different categories

If needed, I can get the Serie :

```
s_items

0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
4  E
5  F
6  G
```

**To be more concrete**, I have products that belong to categories, and I have shops that are associated with a category.
And I want to know in how many shops each product is available, based on the caterogy of each product, and the category of each shop. Hope it's clear ..

- (a,b,c,d) are categories
- (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) are products
- (10,20,25,15) are the number of shops associated for each category

**ex** : product A that is in 3 categories (a,b,d), is available in 45 shops, because 10+20+15 = 45

It's like a "vlookup" in excel.

I'm pretty sure I could do it with an iterrows, but I'm looking for a "beautiful" solution.

I'd like to show you some researchs, but I really have no idea how to do that ..
I tried with merges, or pivot, but it's not really usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
df_item_in_cat.melt().merge(df_charac_by_cat, left_on='variable', right_on='cat')\
   .groupby('value')['charac'].agg(['count','sum'])
```

Output:

```
  value  count  sum
0     A      3   45
1     B      4   70
2     C      1   10
3     D      1   10
4     E      3   60
5     F      2   45
6     G      2   40
```

And, this is with all the column renaming and "housekeeping":

```
df_item_in_cat.melt(value_name='item').merge(df_charac_by_cat, left_on='variable', right_on='cat')\
              .groupby('item')['charac'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()\
              .rename(columns={'count':'cat_nb','sum':'sum_charac'})
```

Output:

```
  item  cat_nb  sum_charac
0    A       3          45
1    B       4          70
2    C       1          10
3    D       1          10
4    E       3          60
5    F       2          45
6    G       2          40
```

Comment: Oh jeez... you should have seen the mess I created (-:

Comment: thank you =) ! that's exatly what I wanted ! Didn't know melt function, it's cool !

Comment: @MatthieuVeron You are welcome and thank you.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

ScottBoston's answer is way better but I still kinda like what I did.

### what I was thinking

1. turn both input dataframes into series so that I can operate over the new index.
2. that index should be based on the values in `df_item_in_cat`
3. i'll count across that index
4. then map values and sum
5. do some accounting work to get column names what they should be

---

```
siic = df_item_in_cat.pipe(
    lambda d: pd.Series(np.tile(d.columns, len(d)), d.values.ravel())
)

scbc = df_charac_by_cat.set_index(['cat']).charac

pd.concat(dict(
    cat_nb=siic.groupby(level=0).count(),
    sum_charac=siic.map(scbc).sum(level=0)
), axis=1, sort=True).rename_axis('item').reset_index()

  item  cat_nb  sum_charac
0    A       3          45
1    B       4          70
2    C       1          10
3    D       1          10
4    E       3          60
5    F       2          45
6    G       2          40
```

Comment: `tile` instead of `repeat`

Answer (score 2):

*Know I'm late, but I kinda liked my solution too ;)*

The first column is easily gotten by using `np.unique`

```
v, _, c = np.unique(df.values, 1, return_counts=True)
```

which yields

```
>>> print(v,c)
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G'], [3 4 1 1 3 2 2]
```

Then

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(v,c)), index=['cat_nb']).T

   cat_nb
A       3
B       4
C       1
D       1
E       3
F       2
G       2
```

The second column is trickier but still manageable using `defaultdict`

```
x = defaultdict(set)
from collections import defaultdict
for d in df.to_dict('r'):
    for k,v in d.items():
        x[v].add(k)
```

such that

```
>>> x
{'A': {'a', 'b', 'd'},
 'B': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
 'E': {'b', 'c', 'd'},
 'C': {'a'},
 'F': {'b', 'c'},
 'D': {'a'},
 'G': {'c', 'd'}}
```

Then we can map that using O(1) lookup of dicts

```
d2 = df2.set_index('cat').to_dict()['charac']
s = pd.Series({k: sum(d2[v_] for v_ in v) for k,v in (x).items()})

dff.loc[:, 'f'] = s
```

And we have the output

```
    cat_nb  f
A   3       45
B   4       70
C   1       10
D   1       10
E   3       60
F   2       45
G   2       40
```

Comment: A wizard is never late.  He arrives precisely when he means to.